# Generic constrain for Lists and Collections

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, generic-constraints

I have a Generic method which looks something like this:

```cs
public int GetCount<T>(T collection) where T: ICollection
{
   return collection.Count;    
}
```

Now I want to be able to call this method where the collection parameter can be a `List<T>` or a `HashSet<T>`. The current code doesn't fulfill that since the parameters I want to pass do not inherit the `ICollection` interface. Now would there be any way I could achieve that with a simple constrain?

Comment: What are you achieving here that isn't best left to `Enumerable`'s `Count` extension method?

Comment: It is part of a bigger method which should be fully generic and should also return the length.

Comment: In that case you can still apply the same mechanism that also `IEnumerable.Count()` implements. You take in your type constraint a wider type (like `IEnumerable`) and within the method you try to cast it to a more specific type to get a fast-path and only if that fails take the slow method of the wider type. For an example take a look at the [Count() extension method](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Count.cs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't:

```
public int GetCount<T>(ICollection<T> collection)
{
   return collection.Count;    
}
```

Comment: Well they do implement the `ICollection<T>` interface. I'll give it a shot hold on.

Comment: @HimBromBeere `typeof(ICollection) != typeof(ICollection<T>)`